# SwypeRefreshLayout не останавливает анимацию во Fragment

Tags: java, android

Есть ViewPager, в нем фрагменты. Во фрагменте SwipeRefreshLayout с ListView
Внутри класса фрагмента в onCreateView задаю

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.SwipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(SwipeRefreshListener);

    private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener SwipeRefreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            new GetDataTask().execute();
        }
    };
```

Все работает. После выполнения всех задач в GetDataTask пишу swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);, но анимация не пропадает. Так и висит. Пытался найти что-то похожее на stackoverflow, но не нашел.

Может кто-то сталкивался, как решить проблему?
Когда раньше фрагментов не было, все работало.

Предлагали уже на другом ресурсе сделать так:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(stopRefreshing, 5000); // время можно уменьшить
}

private final Runnable stopRefreshing = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
};
```

Но это не помогает никоим образом.
Странно то, что он работает через раз. И проблема возникла после того как я перешел на фрагменты.

Код класса выполняемой задачи:

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        setDataAdapter("");
        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        updateListView_PullRefresh();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: А библиотеки все последней версии?.. А то были у `SwipeRefreshLayout` баги при, например, использовании с библиотекой дизайна. Но они были поправлены после.

Comment: И возможно это из за особенностей жизненного цикла фрагментов в пейджере. Покажите как вы из таска обращаетесь к свайпу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я уже подумал на счет библиотек, но в другую сторону. Обновился как раз. Получил кучу проблем после обновления на Eclipse, но после танцев с бубном вроде все заработало. Думаю, может в новых версиях что-то глючит, ведь раньше на ActivityFragment все работало без проблем.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, на счет обращения к свайпу из таска:
  private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
       protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
       swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
          super.onPostExecute(result);
      }
   protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
    updateListView_PullRefresh();
    return null;
   }
  }

Как код-то вставить? В кавычки ставлю не получается..

Comment: В комментах код можно выделить так: "\`"; Но переносы строк не отображаются. Так что дополняйте вопрос через `правка`

Comment: Я что еще подумал. Я как раз перед вставкой фрагментов в свое приложение сделал обновление всего что было предложено. Может какой косяк в обновлении? Раньше ведь это все работало четко.

Comment: Может и так... Попробуте откатиться на пред. версии. Но вот у меня всё работает без нареканий.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:
1) имплементируйте Ваш фрагмент

```
 implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
```

2) Объявите ваш SwyperRefreshLayout таким образом:

```
refreshListViewLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.refreshListViewLayout);
        refreshListViewLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

3) Перекройте метод обновления

```
    @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
 refreshListViewLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            new GetDataTask().execute();
        }
```

4) В Вашем `GetDataTask` внутри `onPostExecute`  выполните  `refreshListViewLayout.setRefreshing(false);`

Таким образом у меня всё работает

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. У меня слушатель был задан без указания implements, подумал в этом дело. Переделал как вы написали. Все равно работает через раз. То остается висеть, то исчезает и работает исправно. Жаль ....

Comment: Что то ему не нравится. Может этому объекту в OnResume нужно сто-то указать. Сначала не работает. Стоит подергать страницы что-бы первая как бы уничтожилась и начинает работать если вернуться на нее.

Comment: а в onPostExecute у Вас постоянно заходит? Под дебагом не смотрели? Может где на эксэпшене отваливается

Comment: да ставил там Log.d всегда туда заходит. Но не всегда срабатывает IsRefreshing(). Возвращает false, но продолжает крутится.